# HTTPS iframe within an HTTP page, how can I stop that?

Tags: security, iframe, https

I'm looking at buying an airline ticket, and I'm having to enter my credit card details in a http:// page, that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Verified by Visa iframe]

If I look at the source code, this is actually an iframe with an HTTPS source, so this actually secure, but a non-tech-savvy user has no way of knowing that. Obviously, this is horrible (even for tech-savvy users).

Now, my question is, if I was the site offering this iframe (Verified by Visa in this case), is there a way that I could force modern browsers to not allow my page to be used as an iframe on http:// pages, but still allow it to be used as an iframe on https:// pages? Is there a technique that Verified by Visa really should be using here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm looking at buying an airline ticket, and I'm having to enter my credit card details in a http:// page

Ouch! Someone's breaking the PCI-DSS terms of their merchant agreement huh.

> If I look at the source code, this is actually an iframe with an HTTPS source, so this actually secure, but a non-tech-savvy user has no way of knowing that.

Indeed. You'd have to look at *all* the source code, including every piece of script on the parent page, to ensure that there is nothing interfering with the iframe (eg via clickjacking) and that the image you see in the browser page actually is the secure iframe. And ensure there were no other tabs open from the same domain with a reference to the window to cross-document-script into it... a non-starter.

> if I was the site offering this iframe (Verified by Visa in this case), is there a way that I could force modern browsers to not allow my page to be used as an iframe on http:// pages, but still allow it to be used as an iframe on https:// pages?

I believe you could do it using [Content Security Policy Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/), eg with the header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https:
```

However support is patchy: at the time of writing, even the latest IE and Safari don't support it, and obviously it didn't exist at the time 3-D Secure implementations were being written. Still, if it just complains some of the time that would be enough to let an unwitting merchant know they'd messed up their payment integration.

One other thing they might have been able to do back then would be to check the Referer header for an http: address. Still not reliable (and maybe tricky to make work for all possible flows including redirect and pop-up, and in-between redirections) but could have helped.